# what does it mean when sq query starts 'with dt as' ? what is the meaning of the dt?

Tags: sql

what does it mean when sq query starts 'with dt as' ? what is the meaning of the dt?

trying to understand why this line is required at the start of the query

Comment: `WITH dt AS (SELECT ...) SELECT ...` -- `dt` is the name of the subquery you are defining inside the parenthesis. In the main query (the last `SELECT`) you can select from `dt` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CTE expression name. Refer below link:
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/